# Ruby instance variables within class?

Tags: ruby

So I was looking over page objects for Ruby testing here:
http://elementalselenium.com/tips/7-use-a-page-object

And down on the page within this bit of code:

```
class GoogleSearch

  SEARCH_BOX        = { id: 'gbqfq'     }
  SEARCH_BOX_SUBMIT = { id: 'gbqfb'     }
  TOP_SEARCH_RESULT = { css: '#rso .g'  }

  attr_reader :driver

  def initialize(driver)
    @driver = driver
    visit
    verify_page
  end

  def visit
    driver.get ENV['base_url']
  end

  def search_for(search_term)
    driver.find_element(SEARCH_BOX).clear
    driver.find_element(SEARCH_BOX).send_keys search_term
    driver.find_element(SEARCH_BOX_SUBMIT).click
  end

  def search_result_present?(search_result)
    wait_for { displayed?(TOP_SEARCH_RESULT) }
    driver.find_element(TOP_SEARCH_RESULT).text.include? search_result
  end

  private

    def verify_page
      driver.title.include?('Google').should == true
    end

    def wait_for(seconds=5)
      Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => seconds).until { yield }
    end

    def displayed?(locator)
      driver.find_element(locator).displayed?
      true
      rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
        false
    end

end
```

It defines `@driver = driver`, but then in all the other methods it uses just `driver`. Shouldn't all the other methods be using the initialized variable `@driver`? Or is this just simply a case of mis-documentation?

I mean after all what was the point of declaring `@driver` if we never use it again?

Comment: `attr_reader :driver` means that `@driver` is accessible as `driver`

Comment: @khelwood without the `attr_reader` would I be able to just use `@driver` without needing that?

Comment: You can use `@driver` within the class if you prefer, with or without the `attr_reader` declaration.

Comment: It has an instance variable and an accessor. Good Ruby style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr_reader :driver` is just a helper (macro) that defines following method:

```
def driver
  @driver
end
```

While `attr_writer :driver` would define the following:

```
def driver=(value)
  @driver = value
end
```

and `attr_accessor :driver` would define both, a reader and writer method.

So whenever you see `driver` it calls the method that accesses `@driver`. It is good practice to access instance variable via a getter. Makes the code easier to refactor.

Assuming you want to raise an exception if `driver` is unset, you can remove the `attr_reader` and add your own definition of `driver` without changing the rest of the code:

```
def driver
  raise "no driver set" if !@driver
  @driver
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`attr_reader :driver` means that `@driver` is accessible as `driver`. When the code refers to `driver`, it is getting `@driver`.

You can use `@driver` within the class if you prefer, with or without the `attr_reader` declaration.

Comment: So I guess what advantage does this give us outside of not having to see the @ sign everywhere?

Comment: It makes `driver` accessible for reading from outside the class, via `instance.driver`. It allows you to replace `driver` with an explicit method if your requirements change (without changing all the code referencing `driver`). It follows normal ruby conventions about having accessors for private instance variables. Same as writing a getter in most object-oriented languages.

Comment: Object-oriented programming is based on message send. A variable dereference is not a message send. You can't override a variable in a subclass. So, the question should not be "why use a method", but rather "why use a variable"?

Answer (score 1):

There is this line `attr_reader :driver` at the top of the class which is a macro for:

```
def driver
  @driver
end
```

The advantage to prefer this getter methods over direct @driver calls is that it makes future refactorings easier.